# How to make an validation so the users can only enter letters

Tags: python

I am writing this code:

```
import random #this imports the random module
#so I can use this later on to create my randomised numbers.
username=input("What is your name?") #this sets the variable username to
#what the user inputs when asked the question "What is your name?"
print ("Hello " + username) #this then prints hello to the user with the
#username variable so it should say hello with the users name.
questions=0 #this will set the question variable to 0 so I can change
#it later on the script when they get asked a question.
score=0 #this will set the score variable to 0 so i can change it 
#further along the script when they get something right.
while questions < 10:
   num1=random.randint(1,12) #this set the variable num1 to a randomised
   #integar between 0-12,this will be  used in the script for the questions.
    num2=random.randint (1,10) #this will then set the variable num2 to a
    #random number inbetween 1 an 10 which will ,again, be used later on.
    operatorlist= ["-","+","X"] #I made a list of the operators so I can    choose
    #a random item on the list by using the random function.
    operator=random.choice(operatorlist)#this will then choose an random
    actualquestion=(num1, operator, num2, "?")
    #operator from the list
    if operator=="+": #this is a if statement which states that if the operator is
    #add then the answer should be num1 add num2 as the add function was randomly
    #picked
```

....
But if the user enters their name as letters the programme crashes. Is there an easy way to make sure users only enter letters and stop them from entering anything else? I dont want to use another loop function? I want it to be simple and hopefully just a few lines of code.

Comment: Just as a side note, comments are good but **too many** comments are not good.

Comment: You can use the `isdigit()` function for strings to check if it's a number. See the *second* answer on the linked question.